# Show that $E[Z_n^2]= \sum_{i=1}^n E[(Z_i-Z_{i-1})^2] $ for a martingale with $Z_0=0$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, martingales

I was just wondering, if we let $(Z_n)_{n\geq 0}$be a martingale with $Z_0=0$, is it true then
$$
E[Z_n^2]= \sum_{i=1}^n E[(Z_i-Z_{i-1})^2] 
$$
Please let me know and if it is true, can someone show me how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
$$
{\rm E}[(Z_i-Z_{i-1})^2]={\rm E}[Z_i^2+Z_{i-1}^2-2Z_iZ_{i-1}],\quad 1\leq i\leq n.
$$
Then use the tower property to deduce that
$$
{\rm E}[Z_iZ_{i-1}]={\rm E}[{\rm E}[Z_iZ_{i-1}\mid\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]]={\rm E}[Z_{i-1}^2],\quad 1\leq i\leq n.
$$
Conclude.

Comment: Thank You so much, I just figured it out.